# C++ TR1 regex - multiline option

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I thought that $ indicates the end of string. However, the following piece of code gives "testbbbccc" as a result, which is quite astonishing to me... This means that $ actually matches end of line, not end of the whole string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    tr1::regex r("aaa([^]*?)(ogr|$)");
    string test("bbbaaatestbbbccc\nddd");
    vector<int> captures;
    captures.push_back(1);
    const std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator end;
    for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator iter(test.begin(), test.end(), r, captures); iter != end; )
    {
        string& t1 = iter->str();
        iter++;
        cout &lt;&lt; t1;
    }
}
```

I have been trying to find a "multiline" switch (which actually can be easily found in PCRE), but without success... Can someone point me to the right direction?

Regards,
R.P.

Comment: which implementation of tr1 are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: as I said below - try \z instead of $

Answer (score 2):

As Boost::Regex was selected for tr1, try the following:

From [Boost::Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_syntax.html)

> Anchors:
>
> A '^' character shall match the start
>   of a line when used as the first
>   character of an expression, or the
>   first character of a sub-expression.
>
> A '$' character shall match the end of
>   a line when used as the last character
>   of an expression, or the last
>   character of a sub-expression.

So the behavior you observed is correct.

From: [Boost Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html) as well:

> `\A` Matches at the start of a buffer
>   only (the same as `` \` ``).
>   `\z` Matches at
>   the end of a buffer only (the same as
>   `\'`).
>   `\Z` Matches an optional sequence
>   of newlines at the end of a buffer:
>   equivalent to the regular expression
>   `\n*\z`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no multiline switch in TR1 regexs. It's not exactly the same, but you could get the same functionality matching everything:

```
(.|\r|\n)*?
```

This matches *non-greedily* every character, including new line and carriage return.

Note: Remember to escape the backslashes `'\'` like this `'\\'` if your pattern is a C++ string in code.

Note 2: If you don't want to capture the matched contents, append '?:' to the opening bracket:

```
(?:.|\r|\n)*?
```